# How to remove the results from else in a "case when " expression while building the table

Tags: mysql, sql

Im trying to build a graph in Chartio using SQL code, i want 3
categories in my results : RunningCosts, StorageCosts and OtherCosts.
The problem is that i have an other category i dont want that appears in the graph.

```
SELECT {DATE_BUCKET.BUCKET('TIMESTAMP_ADD(CAST(`usage_start_time` AS TIMESTAMP), INTERVAL {UTC_OFFSET.RAW} HOUR)', UTC_OFFSET)} AS `Date_BucketOfCreated_At`,
        CASE when((sku.description LIKE "%Licensing Fee%"
                  OR sku.description LIKE "%running%")
                  AND
                    (SELECT value
                     FROM UNNEST(labels)
                     WHERE KEY = "env")="prod"
                  AND
                    (SELECT value
                     FROM UNNEST(labels)
                     WHERE KEY="family")="gaming")THEN "RunningCosts"
            WHEN ((sku.description LIKE "%storage%"
                  OR sku.description LIKE "%SSD%")
                  AND
                    (SELECT value
                     FROM UNNEST(labels)
                     WHERE KEY = "env")="prod"
                  AND
                    (SELECT value
                     FROM UNNEST(labels)
                     WHERE KEY="family")="gaming")THEN "StorageCosts"
            WHEN (sku.description NOT LIKE "%storage%"
                  AND sku.description NOT LIKE "%SSD%"
                  AND sku.description NOT LIKE "%Licensing Fee%"
                  AND sku.description NOT LIKE "%running%"
                  AND
                    (SELECT value
                     FROM UNNEST(labels)
                     WHERE KEY = "env")="prod"
                  AND
                    (SELECT value
                     FROM UNNEST(labels)
                     WHERE KEY="family")="gaming") THEN "OtherCosts"
            ELSE "autre"
        END AS `Origin`,
         ROUND(SUM(cost), 2) AS charges


FROM gcp.gcp_billing_export_v1_00A342_468C35_E1E69C
GROUP BY Date_BucketOfCreated_At,
         Origin
ORDER BY Date_BucketOfCreated_At
```

Comment: You can filter out Other category using WHERE condition.

Answer (score 0):

Since it is a new field, you can't just add to your query a `where` clause. But you can select from the result of that query using `where`.

```sql
SELECT * FROM (
-- ORIGINAL QUERY
) WHERE Origin <> 'autre'
```

Comment: just tried this but "Unrecognized name: Origin at [43:7]" at the line u added

Comment: Thank you but "SELECT list expression references column usage_start_time which is neither grouped nor aggregated at [5:54]" appeared when i changed it like your answer

Comment: If the original query works then there is no reason why querying from it would not work

Comment: i just found my mistake i missplaced the where and forgot to place the "group" and "order" instructions inside the select *